# CORS for SoundCloud API doesn't work for some requests

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, soundcloud

I'm pretty new to Javascript and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

My goal is to retrieve the list of related SoundCloud tracks for a specified track (with it's id) through the SoundCloud API.
While doing my XMLHttpRequest I got this error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
>   resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:49458' is therefore not allowed 
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

So from searching I found out, that it has to have something to do with the CORS Header SoundCloud uses to make GET requests possible.

Looking into the API documentation it says, that error code 500 menas an internal server error on SoundCloud sites. But I've tried the whole day now and I can't believe I'm just getting unlucky.

This is my requesting function:

```
function getRelated(soundcloudID) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/" + soundcloudID +"/related?client_id=1dff55bf515582dc759594dac5ba46e9", false);
    xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
        filterBubble.push(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
        }, false);
    xhr.send();
}
```

I know that this is not the best way to do such an request and I should change it into a callback function. I will do that, but I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with it not functioning.

The request also doesn't work for the top trending songs on SoundCloud (https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/charts?kind=trending&genre=soundcloud:genres:all-music&client_id=1dff55bf515582dc759594dac5ba46e9&q=).

The funny thing now is, that I have no problem with search request via the API. XMLHttpRequests for https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=1dff55bf515582dc759594dac5ba46e9&q= are working just fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

Or am I just stupid and it's because I'm testing with localhost?

Comment: It's better if you remove your client id from the code

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be calling the API with an invalid `soundcloudId`. Taking a look at the [`/tracks` documentation on the SoundCloud docs](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks) there is an example track ID. When I call your function with it, everything succeeds.

So give your function a call with the following ID of `13158665`:

```js
function getRelated(soundcloudID) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/" + soundcloudID + "/related?client_id=1dff55bf515582dc759594dac5ba46e9", false);
  xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
    console.log(xhr.response)
  }, false);
  xhr.send();
}

// works
getRelated('13158665')

// error you described
getRelated('random id')
```